# Can not compile project with ANT

Tags: java, ant, automation, automated-tests, testng

I'm trying to compile project using:

- ant compile

I've receive following error in terminal:

> taskdef class org.testng.TESTNGNGAntTask cannot be found
>    using the classloader AntClassLoader[]

Here is my teskdef from build.xml file

```
<taskdef name="testng" classpath="${test.classpath}"
classname="org.testng.TESTNGNGAntTask" />
```

Comment: is there an important reason why you use ant instead of some more recent build tool like gradle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you include the ant file (by default is named *build.xml*) ?

Ensure you had installed Apache Ant in your computer: open a command line and execute *ant -v*. If appears a version message It's works.

If you find the ant file, include a compile target (or if you have one, modify it) like this:

```
<property name="src" location="src" />
<property name="build" location="build" />
<target name="compile">
    <mkdir dir="${build}" />
    <javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${build}" />
</target>
```

The propierties are just constants.

Good luck!

Comment: Unfortunately it does not help(

Comment: maybe my Build file will helps

Comment: You did not include all the code above! The propiertes are not appear in the build.xml of this link. Please, include the propierties or just change the ${build} and ${src} for a specific location for the files compiled and source files, respectively.

Comment: [javac] Compiling 1 source file to /Users/stakhivigor/Documents/workspace/TestNg2/build
    [javac] /Users/stakhivigor/Documents/workspace/TestNg2/src/testngFiles/Annotations.java:3: error: package org.testng.annotations does not exist
    [javac] import org.testng.annotations.Test;
    [javac]                              ^
    [javac] /Users/stakhivigor/Documents/workspace/TestNg2/src/testngFiles/Annotations.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]  @Test
    [javac]   ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class Test
    [javac]   location: class Annotations
    [javac] 2 errors

Answer (score 0):

The name of the class is [`TestNGAntTask`](http://testng.org/javadocs/org/testng/TestNGAntTask.html) (with one `NG` and with only the `T` of `Test` capitalized), *not* `TESTNGNGAntTask` (with two `NG`'s and an entirely capitalized `TEST`).

Try the following instead:

```
<taskdef name="testng" classpath="${test.classpath}"
    classname="org.testng.TestNGAntTask" />
```

Comment: Unfortunately it does not help(   
dropbox.com/s/0c7ffyidaiqde3w/build.xml?dl=0 
maybe my Build file will helps

Comment: dropbox.com/s/0c7ffyidaiqde3w/build.xml?dl=0 – Igor Stah 53 secs ago

Comment: Looking at your build.xml, I notice: `<path id="classpath_jars"><fileset dir="${ws.jars}" includes="*.jars"/></path>`. The `includes="*.jars"` is unusual. JAR files usually end with `.jar`, not `.jars` with an "s". Should this be changed to `includes="*.jar"`?